# how to get the value of div element for a table row in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and I want to show the value of a row by clicking on it.
In the following I want to show the value of 1

```
<tr class="myTable">
  <div class"Row" id= "myRow">
   <div id=rowID1 > 1 </div>
   <div id=rowID2 > 2 </div>
   <div id=rowID3 > 3 </div>

  </div>
</tr>
```

Thats what I tried:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('myTable')[0].getElementsByClassName('myRow')[0].getElementsById("rowID1")[0];
```

but I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'rowID1'.

When I checked the result for `console.log( document.getElementsByClassName('myTable')[0].getElementsByClassName('myRow')[0])` it showed:

```
<div class"Row" id= "myRow">
   <div id=rowID1 > 1 </div>
   <div id=rowID2 > 2 </div>
   <div id=rowID3 > 3 </div>
```

So up to "myRow" it shows the correct value, but how can I find the div element to show the value of "1" ?

Comment: Why not simply `$('#rowID1').text()` ? But your HTML isn't correct, you can't put divs in a TR without TD.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: This is not valid Javascript code. That is inspired by jQuery, in which you should try to accomplish this in one line, since you already seem to use it.

Comment: You have invalid html syntax correct that first

Comment: "myRow" is an id not a class

Comment: I don't understand. Since when is `getElement...` called from an element, and everyone is replying as if we're using jQuery?

Comment: @karthick: thats the error after I tried yours: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'getElementById'

Answer (score 1):

Try it simply like

```
console.log($('#rowID1'));
```

If your `id's` are **unique**

**Or**

```
console.log($('tr.myTable #myRow #rowID1'));
```

**Updated Full Code**

```
$('tr.myTable #myRow div').on('click',function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: When I tried console.log($('#rowID1')) for every row that that I click I get the value "1" which is the first row! but I want to get the value of each row individually when I click on that.

Comment: and when I tried: console.log($('tr.myTable #myRow #rowID1')); I get a strange result: "[prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: document, selector: "myTable #myRow #rowID1', jquery: "2.0.3", constructor: function…]"

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = document.getElementById('#rowID1').innerHTML
```

Comment: When I tried that, for every row that that I click I get the value "1" which is the first row! but I want to get the value of each row individually when I click on that.

Comment: You will need to do it for each ID

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution ur looking for..http://jsbin.com/eBOFojE/2/edit

```
 $('#myRow div').on('click',function(){
var a = $(this).text();
  alert(a);

})
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

`document.getElementsByClassName('myTable')[0].getElementsByClassName('myRow')[0].getElementById("rowID1");`

You have 'getElementsById', plural. ID's are supposed to be unique, thus, there is no command for getting many ID's. Thus, it doesn't return an array, it just return that one node itself.

So I got rid of the plural `elements` and got rid of the `[0]`th array call.

Comment: Does anyone care to share why this got downvoted? Is it incorrect? Genuine search for knowledge here =)

Comment: thats the error after I tried yours: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'getElementById'